# Dataframe scope issue in shiny between graph and datatable selection

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I create a dataTable from a SQL query and I wish use the input$table_rows_selected function (clicking in the DT Table row view) to update a graph

My problem is the table created is not seen by the output$plot <- renderPlotly function (scoping problem)

How can I do to have this interaction between my dataTable et my graph (including each other a different SQL query) ?

Thank you for your help

Here my UI.R :

```
  mainPanel(
   DT::dataTableOutput("table"), #My Table 
  plotlyOutput("plot")) # My graph
   ))

 refDataFrame <- reactive({
 data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

 SQL query searching all STEP_NAME items
 odbcClose(data_testeur)

Ref_comp
```

})

Here the server.R :

```
   output$Table <- DT::renderDataTable({

   data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

    SQL query to feed my dataTable with a column including all items 
                                                         STEP_NAME
     Close connexion data_testeur

     cpk_total created from the SQL query

     DT::datatable(cpk_total,...) # Formating table
      )


     output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

      another SQL query to trace the graph for 1 STEP_NAME selected
      #This SQL query use a variable from the created cpk_total table

     Close connexion data_testeur

     graph <- ....

       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your code for the data.table in an reactive like this

```
cpk_total <- reactive({
 data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

    SQL query to feed my dataTable with a column including all items 
                                                         STEP_NAME
     Close connexion data_testeur

     return result created from the SQL query
})
```

adnd then call it in `DT::renderDataTable` like this

```
output$Table <- DT::renderDataTable({
     DT::datatable(cpk_total(),...) # Formating table
      })
```

and in `renderPlotly` you can access it aswell

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    dta <- cpk_total()
    data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

      another SQL query to trace the graph for 1 STEP_NAME selected
      #This SQL query use a variable from the created cpk_total table

     Close connexion data_testeur

     graph <- ....

       )
```

good thing with reactive is - it is still only calculated once :-)

Hope this helps

Comment: No problem just happy to help out. If you found the answer helpful please up-vote  as well as accepting.

Comment: Is it possible don't execute the query 2 times because it takes times on the first lauch ( tables about 15GB) ? I mean about  dta <- cpk_total()

Comment: If the query is placed within an reactive it is only performed once as long as all variables e. g. input$xy stays the same. You can check this with putting a call to `browser()` inside the reactive. Every time the code passes the `browser`it will stop and wait for you input. just press `c` to continue. But You will see how often a certain part of the code is evaluated